How to define Apache Camel OPC UA client string syntax to configure multitag aquisition
I'm using Apache Camel OPC UA client to acquire signals from Industrial Gateway OPCUA Server.
My aim is to try to acquire a set of tags value with a sampling interval defined in only a Camel route.
As technologies I'm using:

Spring Boot app with Apache Camel OPC UA client component 3.22.2 LTS version

I'm able to acquire a single tag value with sampling interval to 2000 ms by the following Camel route:
from(milo-client:opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49310?
    keyStoreUrl=file:C:\Temp\application\certificate\clientkeystore.jks
    &keyPassword=123456&keyStorePassword=123456
    &applicationUri=urn:8409:test:camelopcua
    &applicationName=camelopcua
    &node=RAW(ns=2;s=Channel2 SIMUL.SIM_1.BNAp1.18VGG1_1XA)&samplingInterval=2000).log(">>> ${body}")

As written in Camel documentation the node key to define tag value acquisition. See below
node=RAW(ns=2;s=Channel2 SIMUL.SIM_1.BNAp1.18VGG1_1XA)&samplingInterval=2000

Apache Camel OPC UA Client link
Does Apache Camel OPC UA client have the feature to let me define different tags in only camel route?
In case that Camel OPC UA client has implemented the multitag definition in only a route, what is the right string syntax ?

Maybe you can try with the header CamelMiloNodeIds which is taking a list as value, before sending the request to the server: .setHeader("CamelMiloNodeIds", constant(Arrays.asList("nsu=urn:org:apache:camel;s=myitem1")))

@Raphi1 I've already seen the Apache Camel OPCUA Client documentation as written in my post.  Code snippet suggested by Apache Camel OPUA Milo client documentation works fine. I understood that for more than a tag I can't use the method written in my post.
